# How do I update a dict via exclusive measures?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

what I'm trying to do is create keys that don't exist in a dict...
the best way I can think to do this is with:

```
>>> d = dict( a = 'test' )
>>> d['a'] = d.get('a', 'default' )
```

or

```
>>> if 'a' not in d: d['a'] = 'default'
```

the problem I'm having with this is nothing more than a minor annoyance, but it's the fact I have to specify `'a'` twice.

I'm trying not to define a function as this operation is trivial...
I just want to know, is there a better built-in way to do this??

Comment: Errr... `d.setdefault('a', 'default')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just test if the key is not yet present:

```
if 'a' not in d:
    d['a'] = 'default'
```

This doesn't get around the key repetition (which is easily remedied by using a variable), but at least avoids setting the key if it already is there anyway.

If your real goal is to access the current value and set a default if not yet present, use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
value = d.setdefault('a', 'default')
```

This tests for the key, sets a default value, and returns the value for the key, all in one step.

Do take into account the default value expression is executed first, `dict.setdefault()` is not suitable where creating the default is expensive or has side effects.

Comment: thanks, idk where I overlooked `setdefault` from, but that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Tcll just a tip: if the default value is potentially an expensive operation (some function call or something) - go for the membership check and then assign it... (just that I've seen people use `dict.setdefault` like it magically does a check first and then happens do the default value - but that's not how function calls work)

Comment: right, as the object is created before `setdefault` is called ;)